# Kali linux Failed VCE resume (-110)

Tags: boot, graphics-card, kali-linux, amd-radeon

Hellooooo all!

I have been searching the internet on this issue but it was either a bit different or nobody answered.

When I boot my Kali I always have this error message :
`radeon 0000:03:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110).`

Here is a bit of dmesg output:

```
[   56.537615] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[   56.548962] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x00000000001D6000).
[   56.549070] radeon 0000:03:00.0: WB enabled
[   56.549073] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0x000000005d0e5267
[   56.549074] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04 and cpu addr 0x00000000d565a798
[   56.549075] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08 and cpu addr 0x00000000a0e7883f
[   56.549075] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0x0000000023819ee6
[   56.549076] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10 and cpu addr 0x00000000140969a7
[   56.549870] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0x00000000d64b6a65
[   56.650343] radeon 0000:03:00.0: failed VCE resume (-110).
[   56.883769] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   56.883775] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   56.883781] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   56.883792] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 5 usecs
[   56.883799] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 5 usecs
[   57.059527] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 2 usecs
[   57.059533] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[   57.059595] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   57.059663] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   57.059723] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   57.059769] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   57.059823] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   57.731390] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[   57.911372] radeon_dp_aux_transfer_native: 158 callbacks suppressed
[   60.560893] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

Now lspci:

```
sudo lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
```

At last, my linux:

```
uname -a
Linux dog 4.19.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-2kali1 (2019-05-15) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So far the closest solution would have been: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1745728#p1745728

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

"For persistent changes edit file /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf to add the line"

`options radeon vce=0`

"After the next reboot you can check the changes by using"

`systool -vm radeon`

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Unfortunately I don't have the "radeon.conf" file.

This is not a critical issue since it just take more time to boot (I think the boot process waits until it gets a timeout).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Steackfrite

Comment: If you don't have the file, it is safe to just create it. Don't forget to `update-initramfs -u -k all` after that.

Comment: So after adding the file and `update-initramfs -u -k all` (I can't do `systool -vm radeon` as the command is not availble) the pb is still here.

Now the error is not display but I still have the same waiting time before having the graphical interface.
I see only a very quick message like "failed to resume sleeping state" or something similar.

So now, I don't have the initial error printed but the behavior remain the same.